# Porque meu jQuery parou de aceitar $ mas esta aceitado "jQuery"?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Com esse código da erro

```
<script>


$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        html:true,
        animation: true,
        sanitize: false
    })
})


var slide_old = "slide_img0";
var slide = "efeito_slide";


$('#carouselExampleCaptions').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (ev) {
    var id = ev.to;
    switch (id) {
        case 0:

        $("." + slide_old).removeClass( slide )
        $(".slide_img0").addClass( slide );
        slide_old = "slide_img0";

        break;
        case 1:

        $("." + slide_old).removeClass( slide )
        $(".slide_img1").addClass( slide );
        slide_old = "slide_img1";

        break;
        case 2:

        $("." + slide_old).removeClass( slide )
        $(".slide_img2").addClass( slide );
        slide_old = "slide_img2";

        break;
        case 3:

        $("." + slide_old).removeClass( slide )
        $(".slide_img3").addClass( slide );
        slide_old = "slide_img3";

        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
})
```

Mas esse não

```
<script>


    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
            html:true,
            animation: true,
            sanitize: false
        })
    })


    var slide_old = "slide_img0";
    var slide = "efeito_slide";


    jQuery('#carouselExampleCaptions').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (ev) {
        var id = ev.to;
        switch (id) {
            case 0:

            jQuery("." + slide_old).removeClass( slide )
            jQuery(".slide_img0").addClass( slide );
            slide_old = "slide_img0";

            break;
            case 1:

            jQuery("." + slide_old).removeClass( slide )
            jQuery(".slide_img1").addClass( slide );
            slide_old = "slide_img1";

            break;
            case 2:

            jQuery("." + slide_old).removeClass( slide )
            jQuery(".slide_img2").addClass( slide );
            slide_old = "slide_img2";

            break;
            case 3:

            jQuery("." + slide_old).removeClass( slide )
            jQuery(".slide_img3").addClass( slide );
            slide_old = "slide_img3";

            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    })

</script>
```

Porque esta dando erro sendo que a pouco estava funcionado perfeitamente?

Comment: pode explicar melhor? o que devia fazer o código? onde está usando ele?

Comment: Verifique no console do seu navegador o que a variável `$` contém. Algum código provavelmente está sobrescrevendo essa variável.

Comment: como o @user140828 mencionou, algum outro código deve ter sobrescrito a alias "$", vc adicionou recentemente alguma biblioteca js no seu projeto? Aliás, só pra deixar a nota aqui, muita gente não sabe, mas o "$" é só um apelido para o jQuery, poderia ser qualquer outra coisa que não esteja reservada pelo javascript ou esteja sendo usada, e é configurável tb

Comment: @GustavoRichter Richter esse código é para poder colocar html em um popover e coloca e remove uma classe conforme um slide troca de imagem

Comment: @user140828 retorna isso no console Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at (index):524

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É um boa prática quando se utiliza jQuery não utilizar diretamente `$`. Existem algumas formas de referenciar `$` justamente para se evitar os erros que você está tendo.

**Usando um atalho**

```js
// Note que $jq pode ser qualquer nome de variável que você desejar.
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

// Veja o exemplo
$jq( '#link ').css( 'background', 'red' );
```

**Usando uma IIFE**

```js
(function ( $ ) {
   // Dentro deste escopo $ é uma referência ao objeto jQuery
   $( '#link' ).css( 'background', 'red' );
})( jQuery );
```

**Passando $ como argumento na chamada `jQuery( document ).ready()`**

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function ( $ ) {
   // Dentro deste escopo $ é uma referência ao objeto jQuery
   $( '#link' ).css( 'background', 'red' );
});
```

**Usando uma sintaxe mais curta que a anterior**

```js
jQuery(function ( $ ) {
    // Dentro deste escopo $ é uma referência ao objeto jQuery
    $( '#link' ).css( 'background', 'red' );
});
```

Mas você deve estar se perguntando em qual situação devo usar cada sintaxe?

- **Opção 1**:  Indicado quando você possuir outras bibliotecas que também usam  `$` (como `prototype.js` por exemplo) e como o nome da fucionalidade já diz, esta funcionalidade evitará o conflito entre as bibliotecas.
- **Opção 2**: Usando uma [IIFE](https://imasters.com.br/front-end/sobre-funcoes-imediatas-javascript-iife) você cria um escopo interno onde `$` será acessível somente dentro da daquela função. Você pode ou deve utilizar esta sintaxe quando você não quer ou não deseja esperar o dom ser carregado completamente. Por exemplo, quando se tem certeza que seu script será carregado após o(s) elementos(s) que você quer manipular ou você tem certeza que seu script será a última coisa a ser carregada na página.
- **Opções 3 e 4**: Quando a ação que você deseja realizar em seu script necessita que o DOM esteja completamente carregado.

Seu código alterado poderá parecer com trecho de código abaixo:

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function ( $ ) {
    var slide_old = "slide_img0";
    var slide = "efeito_slide";

    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        html:true,
        animation: true,
        sanitize: false
    });   

    $('#carouselExampleCaptions').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (ev) {
        var id = ev.to;
        switch (id) {
            case 0:

            $("." + slide_old).removeClass( slide )
            $(".slide_img0").addClass( slide );
            slide_old = "slide_img0";

            break;
            case 1:

            $("." + slide_old).removeClass( slide )
            $(".slide_img1").addClass( slide );
            slide_old = "slide_img1";

            break;
            case 2:

            $("." + slide_old).removeClass( slide )
            $(".slide_img2").addClass( slide );
            slide_old = "slide_img2";

            break;
            case 3:

            $("." + slide_old).removeClass( slide )
            $(".slide_img3").addClass( slide );
            slide_old = "slide_img3";

            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

**Referência**

- jQuery [summary-of-ways-to-reference-the-jquery-function](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/#summary-of-ways-to-reference-the-jquery-function)

Comment: Muito Obrigado, eu não sabia nem metade  disso e seu código funcionou perfeitamente